Options pricing and assymetric catalysts
What is the consensus or the most popular methods for pricing options for highly assymetric risk/reward events?
Let's assume biotech startup X is developing a drug which has a 10% chance of being FDA approved, after which the price of its shares could skyrocket 10x in case of success or else collapse.
What models are used to price X biotech's options for the day after the big catalyst announcement? How well do they hold empirically?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
